# FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

fulltext match is ignoring its index when I add a number of words conditional for its boolean mode. The selects are as follows:

```
explain select * from seeds  WHERE  MATCH(text) AGAINST ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

outputs

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seeds | fulltext | text          | text | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

the same query with a number of words conditional

```
explain select * from seeds  WHERE  MATCH(text) AGAINST ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) = 4;
```

outputs

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | seeds | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9607 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

surely this cant be correct behaviour?

Comment: Platform and version?

Comment: This question gets a +1 because this symptom caused by FULLTEXT indexes is rarely discussed. +1 for bringing this topic up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **I have very bad news for you**.

Unfortunately, that is the correct behavior.

The MySQL Query Optimizer tends to get sidetracked very easily when using a FULLTEXT index.

#### **I also have very good news for you**.

[I wrote about this in StackOverflow on how to get around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070993/optimizing-mysql-fulltext-search/6092216#6092216).

You may have to nest your original query in a subquery and return the MATCH function as a column. Then, evaluate the MATCH column outside of the subquery.

Instead of your query

```
select * from seeds  WHERE  MATCH(text) AGAINST ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) = 4;
```

you must refactor it into something like this:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT id,MATCH(text) AGAINST
    ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
    FROM seeds
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST
    ("mount cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) A
INNER JOIN seeds B USING (id)
WHERE A.score = 4;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Does this apply to both InnoDB and MyISAM?