# slow query with fulltext and left join

Tags: mysql, select, full-text-search

I have 3 tables

- about 250,000 records.
- table1 is MyISAM, add fullindex with title and content, add index with pid.
- table2 and table3 are InnoDB, add index with pid.

Only query table3, just cost 0.04 seconds.

```
select * from table3 
WHERE MATCH (title,content)
AGAINST ('+words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY pid
```

but query like this, cost 16.87 seconds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pid = table2.pid
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.pid = table3.pid
WHERE MATCH (table3.title, table3.content)
AGAINST ('+words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY table3.pid
```

I make an EXPLAIN plan for the 2nd query, return:

```
id select_type  table     type  possible_keys    key    key_len    ref               rows      Extra
1  SIMPLE       table1    ALL    pid             NULL   NULL       NULL              201497    Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE       table2    ref    pid             pid    32         mydb.table1.pid   1     
1  SIMPLE       table3    ref    pid             pid    32         mydb.table2.pid   222309    Using where
```

- Why is the 2nd query slow?
- How can I optimize it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL is behaving exactly as I expected.

The problem lies in the fact that MySQL's Query Optimizer gets very confused when used in conjunction with other tables in an EXPLAIN plan's compliation. I wrote about this before:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757 (May 23, 2011)
- [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216) (Oct 25, 2011)
- [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730) (Jan 26, 2012)
- [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545) (May 07, 2012)

My suggestion: Try Refactoring the Query By Getting the FULLTEXT Search to occur before JOINs

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pid = table2.pid 
LEFT JOIN
(
    select * from table3  
    WHERE MATCH (title, content) 
    AGAINST ('+words' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
    ORDER BY pid 
) table3
ON table1.pid = table3.pid 
;
```

Comment: Is that still the case? Is that in current version been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This are my tips, if someone want to add something or let me know if I'm wrong I'll appreciate it:

- Remove the * from the select statement, just put the columns that you need.

  ```
  SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pid = table2.pid
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.pid = table3.pid
  WHERE MATCH (
  table3.title, table3.content
  )
  AGAINST (
  '+words'
  IN BOOLEAN
  MODE
  )
  ORDER BY table3.pid
  ```
- If you don't need all the results you can add limit at the end,

  ```
  ORDER BY table3.pid 
  limit 100;
  ```
- If you can try with a like (probably is not faster, but I'm just curious) and let us know how it goes would be great!.. Regards

Comment: `LIMIT` does not necessarily make a query faster.  It depends on whether it has to gather all the rows before performing the `ORDER BY` -- This query is complex enough so it is the case.  When an `INDEX` can do _all_ the `WHERE` _and_ all the `ORDER BY`, then `LIMIT` may have a dramatic speedup.  The index being used is the FULLTEXT index, which does not help with `LEFT` or `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `LIKE` would be a disaster here since you would need (1) leading wildcards and (2) `OR`.  No index would be useful, or at east not for the `LIKE` part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, also this method without left join, could get a faster query, 0.12 seconds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1,table2,table3
WHERE table1.pid = table2.pid 
and table1.pid = table3.pid 
and MATCH (table3.title, table3.content)
AGAINST ('+words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY table3.pid
```

Comment: This is equivalent to changing `LEFT` to `INNER` join.

Comment: if you change * for the columns that you need the values only + using limit, I think you can decrease more those 0.12 sec.