# Is there a way to hint to query optimizer to MySQL which constraints should be done first?

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

This is my current query:

```
SELECT BusinessID as ID,  
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(LatLong),2)+pow(106.772835-Y(LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance from
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
      tableauxiliary
    WHERE
      MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)=1  
    AND Prominent >15 
) AS TA

    Having Distance <= 18238
    ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 45
```

Notice that they I used subquery. The reason why it uses subquery is because I want

```
      MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)=1
```

to be done first. This reduces query time from 19 seconds to .9 seconds.

Is there a way to hint to mysql query optimizer so that I do not need to use subquery

Update:

I tried:

```
SELECT BusinessID as ID,  
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(LatLong),2)+pow(106.772835-Y(LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance from tableauxiliary 
USE Index (LatLong_2,FullTextSearch)
WHERE
    MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)  
    AND Prominent >15 
    AND MATCH FullTextSearch AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY
  Distance
```

Nothing change. If I use explain FullTextSearch is the only index used.

Note: The question is indeed about speed. What happen is I am sure that the query will run faster if mysql optimizer do spatial first before the fulltextsearch. This is because sometimes we are searching for a* in fulltext search that obviously don't limit by much.

Basically I have businesses database for the whole world and I am only interested in businesses within 500 meter square or 10km square at most. So obviously the spatial part will be far more restrictive.

While I am moving to mongodb, it'll be kind of nice if things work too for mysql.

Comment: materialized view is great. But my program is designed to be called by hundreds of millions of users. I wonder if each will have their own materialized view.

Answer (score 8):

I have rather bad news for you in this regard

MySQL Query Optimizer tends to stray away for further optimization once it sees a FULLTEXT index. I have written about this before in the StackExchange

- `May 23, 2011` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757
- `Oct 25, 2011`: [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)

You will have [**refactor the query**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17847/877)

My suggestion would be to do the one of the following

## SUGGESTION #1

- Retrieve Business IDs suing the FULLTEXT Search
- Perform GeoSpatial Search on the Retrieved IDs

## SUGGESTION #2

- Retrieve Business IDs using GeoSpatial Search (Since you said it take 0.9 seconds)
- Perform the FULLTEXT Search on the GeoSpatial-Retrieved Businesses IDs

## SUGGESTION #3

- Retrieve Business IDs using GeoSpatial Search (Since you said it take 0.9 seconds) in Subquery1
- Retrieve Business IDs using FULLTEXT Search in Subquery2
- INNER JOIN Subquery1 and Subquery2

## SUGGESTION #4

- Retrieve Business IDs using GeoSpatial Search (Since you said it take 0.9 seconds)
- DO NOT USE FullTextSerach. Use REGEXP against GeoSpatial-Retrieved Businesses IDs

Here is your original query:

```
SELECT BusinessID as ID,  
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(LatLong),2)+
    pow(106.772835-Y(LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance
from tableauxiliary 
USE Index (LatLong_2,FullTextSearch)
WHERE
    MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)  
    AND Prominent >15 
    AND MATCH FullTextSearch AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY
  Distance;
```

If the MySQL Query Optimizer detects a `FULLTEXT` search along with the conjunction `AND` followed by an expression within the same `WHERE` clause (thus, the same level of evaluation within an EXPLAIN plan), the MySQL Query Optimizer will take a vacation after working with the FULLTEXT search.

Perhaps you could try something like this (from SUGGESTION #1):

```
SELECT BusinessID as ID,  
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(LatLong),2)+
    pow(106.772835-Y(LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance
FROM
(
    SELECT BusinessID,LatLong
    FROM
    (
        SELECT BusinessID,Prominent,LatLong
        From tableauxiliary WHERE
        MATCH FullTextSearch AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) AA
    WHERE Prominent > 15
) A
WHERE
    MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)  
ORDER BY
    Distance
;
```

Notice you do not see the conjunction `AND`. Please check the EXPLAIN plan for this. The query should do the following:

- Gather BusinessID,Prominent,LatLong That Matched the FULLTEXT search
- Remove BusinessID,LatLong Whose Prominent value is < 15
- Check Distance of remaining BusinessID values
- sort the `Check Distance` results by Distance

## **UPDATE 2012-08-08 11:30 EDT**

As stated earlier, the FULLTEXT index seems to abandon all hope of using other indexes. Perhaps two subqueries that are JOINed (SUGGESTION #3)

```
SELECT BusinessID as ID,  
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(LatLong),2)+
    pow(106.772835-Y(LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance
FROM
(
    SELECT BusinessID,Prominent From tableauxiliary WHERE
    MATCH FullTextSearch AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT BusinessID From tableauxiliary WHERE
    MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)
) B
USING (BusinessID)
WHERE Prominent > 15
ORDER BY
    Distance
;
```

You may want to abandon using FULLTEXT searching altogether and try regular expressions (SUGGESTION #4)

```
SELECT B.BusinessID as ID,  
    111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186751-X(B.LatLong),2)+
    pow(106.772835-Y(B.LatLong),2)*0.98838574205337) AS Distance
FROM
(
    SELECT BusinessID From tableauxiliary WHERE
    MBRContains(
    GeomFromText (
        'MULTIPOINT(-6.1934985598076 106.76604791159,-6.1800034401924 106.77962208841)'
        ),
        Latlong)
) A INNER JOIN tableauxiliary B USING (BusinessID)
WHERE B.Prominent > 15 AND
((B.FullTextSearch REGEXP ' a*') OR (B.FullTextSearch REGEXP '^a*'))
ORDER BY
    Distance
;
```

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server we have the option of the [FORCE ORDER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) hint. The only comparable I'm aware of for MySQL is [STRAIGHT_JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always
>   read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases
>   for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

However, I'm inclined to suggest that if you're getting the desired result by using a sub-query, stick with it.

Comment: Just in case anyone is curious, the bounty was awarded for giving traction/views to the question.