# Less restrictive query return less result due to simple removing one additional constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, spatial

Look at this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
   join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
MBRContains(
   GeomFromText ('MULTIPOINT(-6.2317830813328 106.72621691867,-6.1382169186672  106.81978308133)'),
   TA.Latlong
   )
   AND
MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('kucing*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 20
```

that's basically search all bizs whose TA.LatLong is in the box of 'MULTIPOINT(-6.2317830813328 106.72621691867,-6.1382169186672  106.81978308133)' and after that the box must contain kucing

This returns 22 rows.

Now compared that to this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
   join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
MBRContains(
   GeomFromText ('MULTIPOINT(-6.2317830813328 106.72621691867,-6.1382169186672  106.81978308133)'),
   TA.Latlong
   )
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 20
```

It's the same query but LESS restrictive. Now I only want to check whether the business is in the box or not. That is it. Yes there are businesses in those box. Most of which do not contain the word "kucing*"

There should be more queries. Yet there are less. The second query return null. The LESS restrictive query return LESS result.

Rolando answer is good with one catch.

The one with 
    MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('kucing*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) is the one that works properly.

I am asking why the one without is problematic. Rolando seems to try to correct the correct ones.

Note: (I wonder whether this should be another question). After listening to others I tried:
After removing distinct

```
SELECT 
  TB.ID,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1939967464102 106.76400325359,-6.1760032535898 106.78199674641)'
            ),
            TA.Latlong) 
AND TA.Prominent >15
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 20
```

returning 0 rows

Then I tried removing the order by and limit

```
SELECT 
  TB.ID,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  MBRContains(
        GeomFromText (
            'MULTIPOINT(-6.1939967464102 106.76400325359,-6.1760032535898 106.78199674641)'
            ),
            TA.Latlong) 
AND TA.Prominent >15
```

Which also result in 0 rows finally I use the original query and make sure I only remove

```
    AND
MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('kucing*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

to turn results from some results to no results

Finally I make the query really simple

```
SELECT BusinessID, Prominent
FROM
    tableauxiliary as TA
WHERE
  MBRContains(GeomFromText ('MULTIPOINT(-6.2209869856406 106.73701301436,-6.1490130143594 106.80898698564)'),TA.Latlong)
```

That's it the most basic query ever.

Still return no result

Now here's a miracle. I add 2 characters and it works again. The characters I add is =1

```
SELECT BusinessID
FROM tableauxiliary AS TA
WHERE MBRContains( GeomFromText( 'MULTIPOINT(-6.2209869856406 106.73701301436,-6.1490130143594 106.80898698564)' ) , TA.Latlong )
 =1
```

I got result

I guess it's time to report bugs.

Comment: How can the first query return 22 rows when you've said to limit to 20?

Comment: I think I once unlimit the row and it says there are 22.

Comment: did the first query you gave in the question above (as it is written) return 20 or 22?  If it is different from the unlimited one which did return 22, are you 100% sure there were no other differences?

Comment: I'll try again to make sure.

Comment: @Jim: WHat happens when you remove the `DISTINCT` and the `LIMIT` (from both queries)?

Comment: I'll check things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the second (indeed less restrictive) query returns zero rows while the first returns more than zero rows, then this is a bug.

First check if you can repoduce the error with only table or not. If the error stays while you remove the `DISTINCT` and/or the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT`.

Then try to write the set of statements (`CREATE` tables, `INSERT` rows, and the 2 queries, as simplified as possible) that reproduces the error, so others can test.

Then you can submit it to MySQL.

Comment: If you really want to try identifying the cause, you could try several versions of the query (rewriting it) and several versions of similar queries (like my suggestion, removing/adding stuff) and checking which give consistent and which inconsistent results.

Comment: I have a hunch that it may be related to the use of both a spatial function/index (MBRContains) and a Full Text index (and possibly the joining).

Answer (score 4):

The FULLTEXT index acts very funny with regard to the MySQL Query Optimizer. I have written about this before:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757 (May 23, 2011)
- [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216) (Oct 25, 2011)
- [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730) (Jan 26, 2012)
- [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545) (May 07, 2012)

Try refactoring your first query so that the FULLTEXT clause and the Spatial clause are not performed in the same level of the EXPLAiN plan.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        TB.ID,
        TB.Latitude,
        TB.Longitude,
        111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2) + 
        pow(106.773 - TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM `tablebusiness`
        WHERE MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST
        ('kucing*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) AS TB
    join 
    (
        SELECT ID FROM tableauxiliary
        WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText ('MULTIPOINT
        (-6.2317830813328 106.72621691867,-6.1382169186672 106.81978308133)'),TA.Latlong)
    ) as TA
    on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
    ORDER BY
        Distance
) AA LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: I was on the verge of commenting on the question 'weird'.  Now I must say that this is the weirdest of all...  Can't imagine anything like that in other RDBMSes I'm more or less familiar with.

Comment: I agree with you. The answer is even more bizare than the question. I will give it a try.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the query with the fulltext search behave as expected. I want the query without the full text search to work too. I am displaying the query with the full text search to show that there are indeed points within the rectangle I want.