# What is the syntax for querying a spatial column?

Tags: mysql, spatial

What is the right syntax to get all the points within the bounding box? The table consists of a lat and lng column and a spatial column "pt" generated from the lat/lng values.

```
calculated the topleft and bottomright coords for the MBR

tested with the following query ( without the haversine )

SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE (lng BETWEEN 4.88263070241 AND 4.90030729759) 
  AND (lat BETWEEN 52.3677890788 and 52.3785809212);
```

testing the spatial column generates an error

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE MBRWITHIN(pt, MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605))
```

This will give null results

```
SELECT * FROM tb_gps as t WHERE MBRCONTAINS( GeomFromText( 'MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605)' ) , t.pt )=1;
```

The mysql version is

```
protocol_version    10
version     5.1.68-cll
```

It could be that I am using the wrong syntax, am not sure. Could someone help me out with this

( the coords in the second query are different, but that's not really the point)

**edit**

I had success with this query(at least I got some results back, so I am going to work on that a little more)

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    tb_gps
    WHERE   MBRContains
                    (
                    LineString
                            (
                            Point
                                    (
                                    4.8914691 + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS( 52.373185))),
                                     52.373185 + 10 / 111.1
                                    ), 
                            Point
                                    (
                                    4.8914691 - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(52.373185))),
                                     52.373185 - 10 / 111.1
                                    ) 
                            ),
                    pt
                    )
```

Comment: I am glad you are working through this one. +1 for your due diligence. Sorry I could not help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [**MBRContains**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/relations-on-geometry-mbr.html)

I have an example from a previous post : [Less restrictive query return less result due to simple removing one additional constraint](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19661/less-restrictive-query-return-less-result-due-to-simple-removing-one-additional/19682#19682)

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-05-08 17:05 EDT

You have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE MBRWITHIN(pt, MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605))
```

Put the MULTIPOINT in quotes

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE MBRWITHIN(pt, 'MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605)')
```

I did this in [my example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/relations-on-geometry-mbr.html)

## UPDATE 2013-05-08 17:39 EDT

If `MULTIPOINT` is not working for you, try using `POLYGON`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE
    IF(CONTAINS(GeoFromText('POLYGON(52.3641917981 4.87673850395,
    4.87673850395 4.90619949605,4.90619949605 52.3821782019,
    52.3821782019 52.3641917981)'pt),1,0)
;
```

You know something? It just dawned on me. You have the parameters backwards.

You have

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE MBRWITHIN(pt,'MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605)')
```

Try reversing the parameters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_gps 
WHERE MBRWITHIN('MULTIPOINT(52.3641917981 4.87673850395, 52.3821782019 4.90619949605)',pt)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: the new query with MBRCONTAINS did not work, maybe it has to do with how I use MULTIPOINT? I have added the coords for the bounding box to MULTIPOINT, maybe that's wrong? I have to read some sql pages I guess.

Comment: I posted an update to my answer

Comment: yes, I have try'd that too..see updated question. Is MULTIPOINT not just for testing if there is litterly an exact point that matches with a point in the database? Can it be used as a bounding box?http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-class-multipoint.html

Comment: without the =1 at the end of the query, I get a #1416 error

Comment: No, it's annoying, but all of the combinations diddn't work, wasn't the wkb syntax the old syntax, maybe I need that. Am just guessing now ofcourse..