# Possible INDEX on a VARCHAR field in MySql

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search, varchar

I am working in a **MySql database**, with a table like this:

```
+--------------+
|  table_name  |
+--------------+
|    myField   |
+--------------+
```

...and I need to make a lot of queries like this *(with 5-10 strings in the list)*:

```
SELECT myField FROM table_name
WHERE myField IN ('something', 'other stuff', 'some other a bit longer'...)
```

There will be around 24.000.000 **unique rows**

**1)** Should I use a `FULLTEXT` or and `INDEX` key for my `VARCHAR(150)`?
**2)** If I increase the chars from 150 to 220 or 250... would it make a great difference? *(Is there any way to calculate it?)*
**3)** As I said, they are going to be unique, so *myField* should be a **PRIMARY KEY**. Isn't it rare to add a PRIMARY KEY to a field which is already a VARCHAR INDEX/FULLTEXT?

Comment: you do not need to use PRIMARY for uniqueness. There is already UNIQUE for that.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1 : Standard Indexing

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    myfield varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id),
    key (myfield)
);
```

If you index like this, you can either look for the whole string or do left-oriented LIKE searches

## SUGGESTION #2 : FULLTEXT Indexing

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    myfield varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id),
    fulltext (myfield)
);
```

You can effectively use searches for individual keywords as well as whole phrases. You will need to define a custom stopword list because [MySQL will not index 543 words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Here are my other posts from the past two years on FULLTEXT indexes

- `May 23, 2011` : [Optimizing mysql fulltext search (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757)
- `Oct 25, 2011` : [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)

## SUGGESTION #3 : Hash Indexing

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    myfield varchar(255) not null,
    hashmyfield char(32) not null,
    primary key (id),
    key (hashmyfield)
);
```

If you are looking for one specific value and those values could be lengths well beyond 32 characters, you could store the hash value:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myfield,hashmyfield)
VALUES ('whatever',MD5('whatever'));
```

That way, you just search for hash values to retrieve results

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE hashmyfield = MD5('whatever');
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I don't have reputation enough to vote your answer up but I must say it was GREAT. Thank you for the explanation and the examples. I think the hash indexing is the best for my case, it is an awesome solution. But still one question: what do you think the limit of rows for fast searches in the table is going to be? _[using as KEY the VARCHAR(32) for searches]_

Comment: The hash option here is still a text and 32 bytes for what is really 16 bytes.  You can use use a bigint field with conv(left(md5('whatever'),16),16,-10).  There's not a 16 byte numeric but you may find half of the md5 sufficient and then it's only 8 bytes in the index

Comment: It is not good to use MD5 or SHA1 to produce strings which will be indexed. Distribution of strings produced by hashing functions like MD5 or SHA1 is random in a large space which decreases efficiency of your index, which can slow down INSERT and SELECT statements. Here is post explaining it: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-choose-right-data-type-for-a-primary-key-in-mysql-database/

Comment: I apologise as this is an old thread, but my question related directly to this but I am not able to get a clear answer for my needs from reading over the above and other similar articles. My scenario is: I'm developing a very rudimentary stock system which consists of only one table for now. It is accessed externally through an API so all the configuration is held elsewhere - which is the reason why we only need a single table. The two columns which I am thinking about indexing, would have approximately 200 unique entries each, of length < 20 characters. Should I consider adding indexes?

Comment: Is this left-oriented like search `like 'a%'` ?

Comment: @Mike You should post a question on your own, maybe adding a link to this thread to add completeness to what you're asking :-)

Comment: @Rolando, re "*MySQL will not index 543 words*"; Meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier The standard stopword list that is built-in for MyISAM has 543 words. They will never enter in the FULLTEXT index (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes). The same goes for the 36 built in words for InnoDB (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes). What I recommend it to create your own stopword list. I usually use 'a','an', and 'the' in my stopword lists (See my StackOverlow post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757)

Comment: @Pacerier once you create your own stopword list, you will have to recreate your Fulltext Indexes, just be prepared for them to be bigger because of allowing for more words.

Answer (score 24):

MySQL enables you to define prefixed index which means you define first N characters from original string to be indexed, and the trick is to choose a number N that’s long enough to give good selectivity, but short enough to save space. The prefix should be long enough to make the index nearly as useful as it would be if you’d indexed the whole column.

Before we go further let us define some important terms. **Index selectivity** is ratio of *the total distinct indexed values and total number of rows*. Here is one example for test table:

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  | value     |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | abc       |
| 2   | abd       |
| 3   | adg       |
+-----+-----------+
```

If we index only the first character (N=1), then index table will look like the following table:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| indexedValue  | rows      |
+---------------+-----------+
| a             | 1,2,3     |
+---------------+-----------+
```

In this case, index selectivity is equal to IS=1/3 = 0.33.

Let us now see what will happen if we increase number of indexed characters to two (N=2).

```
+---------------+-----------+
| indexedValue  | rows      |
+---------------+-----------+
| ab             | 1,2      |
| ad             | 3        |
+---------------+-----------+
```

In this scenario IS=2/3=0.66 which means we increased index selectivity, but we have also increased the size of index. Trick is to find the minimal number N which will result to maximal *index selectivity*.

There are two approaches you can do calculations for your database table. I will make demonstration on the [this database dump](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db).

Let's say we want to add column *last_name* in table *employees* to the index, and we want to define the smallest number *N* which will produce the best index selectivity.

First let us identify the most frequent last names:

```
select count(*) as cnt, last_name from employees group by employees.last_name order by cnt

+-----+-------------+
| cnt | last_name   |
+-----+-------------+
| 226 | Baba        |
| 223 | Coorg       |
| 223 | Gelosh      |
| 222 | Farris      |
| 222 | Sudbeck     |
| 221 | Adachi      |
| 220 | Osgood      |
| 218 | Neiman      |
| 218 | Mandell     |
| 218 | Masada      |
| 217 | Boudaillier |
| 217 | Wendorf     |
| 216 | Pettis      |
| 216 | Solares     |
| 216 | Mahnke      |
+-----+-------------+
15 rows in set (0.64 sec)
```

As you can see, the last name *Baba* is the most frequent one. Now we are going to find the most frequently occurring *last_name* prefixes, beginning with five-letter prefixes.

```
+-----+--------+
| cnt | prefix |
+-----+--------+
| 794 | Schaa  |
| 758 | Mande  |
| 711 | Schwa  |
| 562 | Angel  |
| 561 | Gecse  |
| 555 | Delgr  |
| 550 | Berna  |
| 547 | Peter  |
| 543 | Cappe  |
| 539 | Stran  |
| 534 | Canna  |
| 485 | Georg  |
| 417 | Neima  |
| 398 | Petti  |
| 398 | Duclo  |
+-----+--------+
15 rows in set (0.55 sec)
```

There are much more occurences of every prefix, which means we have to increase number N until the values are almost the same as in the previous example.

Here are results for N=9

```
select count(*) as cnt, left(last_name,9) as prefix from employees group by prefix order by cnt desc limit 0,15;

+-----+-----------+
| cnt | prefix    |
+-----+-----------+
| 336 | Schwartzb |
| 226 | Baba      |
| 223 | Coorg     |
| 223 | Gelosh    |
| 222 | Sudbeck   |
| 222 | Farris    |
| 221 | Adachi    |
| 220 | Osgood    |
| 218 | Mandell   |
| 218 | Neiman    |
| 218 | Masada    |
| 217 | Wendorf   |
| 217 | Boudailli |
| 216 | Cummings  |
| 216 | Pettis    |
+-----+-----------+
```

Here are results for N=10.

```
+-----+------------+
| cnt | prefix     |
+-----+------------+
| 226 | Baba       |
| 223 | Coorg      |
| 223 | Gelosh     |
| 222 | Sudbeck    |
| 222 | Farris     |
| 221 | Adachi     |
| 220 | Osgood     |
| 218 | Mandell    |
| 218 | Neiman     |
| 218 | Masada     |
| 217 | Wendorf    |
| 217 | Boudaillie |
| 216 | Cummings   |
| 216 | Pettis     |
| 216 | Solares    |
+-----+------------+
15 rows in set (0.56 sec)
```

This are very good results. This means that we can make index on column *last_name* with indexing only first 10 characters. In table definition column *last_name* is defined as `VARCHAR(16)`, and this means we have saved 6 bytes (or more if there are UTF8 characters in the last name) per entry. In this table there are 1637 distinct values multiplied by 6 bytes is about 9KB, and imagine how this number would grow if our table contains million of rows.

You can read other ways of calculating number of *N* in my post [Prefixed indexes in MySQL](http://code-epicenter.com/prefixed-index-in-mysql-database).

**Using MD5 and SHA1 functions in order to generate values which should be indexed is also not good approach**. Why? Read it in post [How to choose right data type for a primary key in MySQL database](http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-choose-right-data-type-for-a-primary-key-in-mysql-database/)

Comment: This is a very verbose answer to a different question.

Comment: Are you kidding me?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong, or what can't be applied to the question?

Comment: Hey MrD. I actually like your answer. Why ? In my old answer, I said in SUGGESTION #1 : `If you index like this, you can either look for the whole string or do left-oriented LIKE searches`. I also said in SUGGESTION #3 : `If you are looking for one specific value and those values could be lengths well beyond 32 characters, you could store the hash value:`. Your answer adequately demonstrates why one should not use huge keys and should index on leftmost characters, which can make a difference in performance. Your answer belongs here. +1 for your answer and Welcome to the DBA StackExchange.

Comment: @Mr.M, shouldn't you be using index on hash instead? That would give you maximum index selectivity, and as a bonus you can choose how close to 100% you wish to be simply by increasing/decreasing N.

Comment: @Mr.M wanted to read your blog (http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-choose-right-data-type-for-a-primary-key-in-mysql-database/) post but it seems to no longer be there?

Answer (score 0):

The mariab `sha2()` function lets you create a (virtual) column of 256 characters (or bytes, documentation is quite unclear here). Using a virtual stored column would let you index and find. But as collisions might occur, some additional selecting might be needed.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  And virtual column searches are not going to be fast !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).