# Is inserting in a MySQL table with a Full-Text index really slow?

Tags: mysql

Reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html), I see this mention :

> For large data sets, it is much faster to load your data into a table
> that has no FULLTEXT index and then create the index after that, than
> to load data into a table that has an existing FULLTEXT index.

I understand the requirements behind building the index, but how "much [slower]" is it to directly insert data into a table with a FULLTEXT index? Is there actual data to give an idea of this?

I need to create a table which will perform about 2,000 inserts each day, and we expect this amount to climb up to 5,000 inserts in the next years. So, between about 70k and 180k entries each year.

So, I'm trying to assess if I really need to have two tables, i.e. one without an index, and another with a full-text index, or if I can insert directly into the table with the full-text search with negligible impact over time.

There are no DBAs, here, and the current MySQL installation went through a few updates already over the last +decade, so there is nothing fancy going on with the current setup.

Thank you for any useful information you can provide me with.

---

### ** Edit **

I typically create tables using the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 1):

A few inserts per minute; not a problem.  A million rows; not a problem.

I am assuming the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

The quote that you mention refers to the initial loading of a large number of rows.  It sounds like you are starting with an empty table and adding a few thousand each day.

I suggest you do `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB` after a few weeks.  This will rebuild the `FULLTEXT` index.  (It seems that `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` indexes are not well designed for gradual loading, hence a periodic rebuild may help.  Regular indexes do not suffer from this.)

I do not know how (or how much) this rebuild advice will help.  But it won't hurt, other than locking up the table for maybe minutes.

If you are actually seeing sluggish inserts, please time one of them for us.  Plus provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It may take a while (read years) before we reach millions of rows on that table, but I'll try still be breathing (and work for the same employer) once we get there :)

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the documentation correct in saying this, but this essentially true for any type of index let alone a FULLTEXT index. When bulk loading a table, the fewer indexes you have the faster it loads.

What you seem to be concerned with is the day-to-day inserts, and you are right in  your gut feeling.

Your first concern should be having the necessary indexes for a table. If it calls for a FULLTEXT index, make sure you have the with combination of columns. You will also need to focus on structuring your queries so that using a FULLTEXT index is worth it. Sometimes, the MySQL Query Optimizer tends to butt heads with FULLTEXT indexes and ends up ignoring them unless you design the query properly.

Here are some old posts I wrote about it and I adamantly believe hold true even today

- `Oct 25, 2011`: [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)
- [... and more](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20fulltext%20indexes)

Now in terms of any negative impact, writing a good FULLTEXT SELECT for performance outweighs insert performance over time. You many need to run ANALYZE TABLE now and then but you seem to have low enough INSERT traffic not to need to.